# how to get the price of the last 3 days in Power BI Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

[Aswer should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcQRj.png)Hi I want to calculate the price of the vehicle 3day before for every day extract into a new column

I used the below formula and I am not getting correct value

```
3dayPrice = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[DailyRate]),FILTER(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing,DATEADD(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Extract Date],-3,DAY)))
```

[image]
Hi I need the values like below For selected Pickup date and selected car, the values should show the extract date-3days price for every extract just like in the below sample Car
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJCgK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ALL inside FILTER to remove context filter (row context)

```
Price3dayAgo = CALCULATE(sum(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[DailyRate]),FILTER(ALL(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing) PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Extract Date] = SELECTEDVALUE(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Extract Date]) -3 ))

AVGofLast3Days = CALCULATE(AVG(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[DailyRate]),FILTER(ALL(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing) PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Extract Date] >= SELECTEDVALUE(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Extract Date]) -3 && PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Extract Date] < SELECTEDVALUE(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Extract Date])))
```

If we need to check additional condition for example Car

&& SELECTEDVALUE(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Car])   = PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Car]

Comment: Hi I need the values like  below
For selected Pickup date and selected car, the values should show the extract date-3days price for every extract just like in the below sample
Car Extractdate Price 3day back price
Mid size 22/06/2021 133.23 94.1
Mid size 21/06/2021 124.47 144.23
Mid size 20/06/2021 112.18 118.65
Mid size 19/06/2021 94.1          98.35
Mid size 18/06/2021 144.23 115.42
Mid size 17/06/2021 118.65 
Mid size 16/06/2021 98.35 
Mid size 15/06/2021 115.42

Comment: Edit your main question and add this example (with proper format). From the comment section is very hard to read your data.

Comment: Added the example in the main question

Comment: add in FILTER

&& SELECTEDVALUE(PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Car]) = PowerBI_HistoricalMarketPricing[Car]